# Is there a way to get notification data if user opens application from launcher without clicking notification?

Tags: android

I have got notification from FCM. And i have opened the app from launcher without clicking the notification. So i dont get the notification data in activity. Is there a way to get notification data if user opens application from launcher without clicking notification?

Comment: Firstly share the payload you are getting from notification, then tell me why you need notification data in app when the app opened from launcher not by clicking on notification

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends upon the app status to get notification data without clicking on Notification,

**onMessageReceived** is provided for most message types, with the following exceptions:

**Notification messages delivered when your app is in the background.**
 In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray. A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.

**Messages with both notification and data payload, both background and foreground**.
 In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

[image: In Summary]

I shared this data just to inform you that the answer provided by @Sagar Zala will not work when your app is in **Background**

[FCM onMessageReceived Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly get notification data if you opens app from launcher icon.

But in this case you can store notification data in **SQLite** or **Shared Preference** while notification arrive and use this data when you opens app from launcher icon.

Note: Clear notification data once app opens.

Thanks.